# How to get a variable that is inside onItemSelected method on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, variables, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I'm trying to get the value of an item that is inside a Spinner, and then I want to send it to a database.
However, the code:
String variable = spinner_name.getSelectedItem().toString() does not work at all

So it seems the best way is through of the method:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But how do you get the value of this variable called text, which is inside the above method, to insert into another method?

Comment: If the other method is accessible from this scope you can call it and pass `text` as one of the parameters of the call. Is the other method accessible? We don't really see it in the code and we don't know the structure of your application. If the other method just needs this value without being called and is part of this same class, then you can make a field called `text` in this class scope and set it with `this.text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();`

Answer (score 1):

Create a CustomAdapter for your spinner, pass a callback as parameter when creating the customAdapter. Once you click on a item on spinner, because of callback, you'll have the item on your frag/activity.

From there you can call any method you want.